# Woocommerce - Call to undefined method WC_Order::get_order_discount()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, deprecated

I just updated to Woocommerce 3.3.5 and it appears that the `get_order_discount()` function has been deprecated. The plugin that is calling it is **woocommerce-gateway-paypal-pro** which has not put out any updates to resolve this issue. I searched through Woocommerce's function reference and for the life of me cannot find the function that replaces `get_order_discount()`.

If anyone with a bit of **Woocommerce** expertise could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet would be to contact support for that plugin!